# Update a single item in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have some data - I'd like to update a boolean in a single object.

The below works - It just seems like a really long way to do something so simple?

Also - If I were to change `letter: "c"`, it would be c at the front of the array, which would be incorrect.  So is there a good way to maintain the order?

Thanks!!

```
// initial data
let data = [
  { letter: "a", number: 1, bool: true },
  { letter: "b", number: 2, bool: true },
  { letter: "c", number: 3, bool: true },
  { letter: "d", number: 4, bool: true },
  { letter: "e", number: 5, bool: true },
  { letter: "f", number: 6, bool: true },
  { letter: "g", number: 7, bool: true },
  { letter: "h", number: 8, bool: true },
  { letter: "i", number: 9, bool: true }
];

// get the row I need to change
const rowToChange = data.find(item => {
  return item.letter === "a";
});

// remove that row from data
data = data.filter(document => {
  return document !== rowToChange;
});

// updates the boolean value
rowToChange.bool = !rowToChange.bool;

// puts it back into the array
data = [rowToChange, ...data];
```

Comment: Check Array.prototype.splice (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Why do you need you need the `filter` and *"put it back into the array"*? Just getting the `row` and updating the object should be enough

Comment: Just remove the `data = data.filter()` and `data = [rowToChange, ...data];` steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're using is to (usually) ensure that you don't mutate the original data. If mutating the data is *not* an issue (and it doesn't look like it is) you can just drop some of the code. I've used [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) here instead of `find`:

```js
let data = [
  { letter: "a", number: 1, bool: true },
  { letter: "b", number: 2, bool: true },
  { letter: "c", number: 3, bool: true },
  { letter: "d", number: 4, bool: true },
  { letter: "e", number: 5, bool: true },
  { letter: "f", number: 6, bool: true },
  { letter: "g", number: 7, bool: true },
  { letter: "h", number: 8, bool: true },
  { letter: "i", number: 9, bool: true }
];

const rowToChange = data.findIndex(item => {
  return item.letter === "c";
});

data[rowToChange].bool = !data[rowToChange].bool;

console.log(data);
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using `findIndex`? OP's code with `find` also does this.

Comment: @adiga, `find` returns the object that matches the condition which isn't useful if you only need the index.

Comment: Thanks @Andy  Works a treat! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this, if you do not have some restrictions to the task

```
data.forEach(item => {
    if (item.letter == "a") {
       item.bool = !item.bool;
    }
});
```

Comment: This will iterate always to the end of the array. Sometimes not being necessary.

Answer (score 0):

With ES6, you can easily update a property of one object in your array using the `map`function :

```
let data = [
  { letter: "a", number: 1, bool: true },
  { letter: "b", number: 2, bool: true },
  { letter: "c", number: 3, bool: true },
  { letter: "d", number: 4, bool: true },
  { letter: "e", number: 5, bool: true },
  { letter: "f", number: 6, bool: true },
  { letter: "g", number: 7, bool: true },
  { letter: "h", number: 8, bool: true },
  { letter: "i", number: 9, bool: true }
];

console.log(data.map(d =>
  d.letter === 'c'
    ? { ...d, bool: false }
    : d
));
```

This will produce the following output :

```
[
  { letter: "a", number: 1, bool: true },
  { letter: "b", number: 2, bool: true },
  { letter: "c", number: 3, bool: false },
  { letter: "d", number: 4, bool: true },
  { letter: "e", number: 5, bool: true },
  { letter: "f", number: 6, bool: true },
  { letter: "g", number: 7, bool: true },
  { letter: "h", number: 8, bool: true },
  { letter: "i", number: 9, bool: true }
]
```

Comment: This will iterate always to the end of the array. Sometimes not being necessary.